# How do I test a class's method that has arguments using sinon.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

Hi I am using `sequelize` ORM with `Postgres` database for this `node.js` `express.js` app. As for testing I am using `mocha`, `chai` and `sinon`.

I am trying to complete a test for a class's method. The class instant i call it `userService` and the method is `findOneUser` .. This method has got an argument `id` .. So in this moment I want to test for a `throw error` the test works **if I dont put an argument.** That means this test is obviously not complete.

Here is the class method I want to test

userService.js

```
module.exports = class UserService {

  async findOneUser(id) {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: id } }); // if null is returned error is thrown

      if (!user) {
        throw createError(404, "User not found");
      }
      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my test code

userService.spec.js

```
describe.only("findOne() throws error", () => {
  let userResult;
  const error = customError(404, "User not found"); // customError is a function where I am throwing both status code and message
      before("before hook last it block issue withArgs" , async () => {

        // mockModels I have previously mocked all the models 
        mockModels.User.findOne.withArgs({ where: { id: fakeId } }).resolves(null); // basically have this called and invoked from calling the method that it is inside of based on the argument fakeId

        userResult = sinon.stub(userService, "findOneUser").throws(error); // this is the class instances method I wonder how to test it withArguments anything I try not working but SEE BELOW COMMENTS

      });

      after(() => {
        sinon.reset()
      });

      it("userService.findOneUser throws error works but without setting arguments ", () => {
        expect(userResult).to.throw(error);
      });
/// this one below still not working
      it("call User.findOne() with incorrect parameter,,  STILL PROBLEM ", () => {
        expect(mockModels.User.findOne).to.have.been.calledWith({ where: { id: fakeId } });
      })
});
```

But for the method of my class `findOneUser` has an argument (id) how can I pass that argument into it where I am stubbing it?

Or even any ideas on how to fake call the class method?? I want both `it` blocks to work

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention I have stubbed the mockModels.User already and that was done before the `describe` block

```
  const UserModel = {
    findByPk: sinon.stub(),
    findOne: sinon.stub(),
    findAll: sinon.stub(),
    create: sinon.stub(),
    destroy: sinon.stub()
  }

  const mockModels = makeMockModels( { UserModel } );  
  // delete I am only renaming UserModel to User to type things quicker and easier
  delete Object.assign(mockModels, {['User']: mockModels['UserModel'] })['UserModel']

  const UserService = proxyquire(servicePath, {
    "../models": mockModels
  });
  const userService = new UserService();
  const fakeUser = {  update: sinon.stub() }
```

Comment: If you're trying to *test* the `findOneUser` method, you should *not* `stub` it?!

Comment: is it not stubbed at where I am assigning ``userResult`` to it inside the ``before`` block? @Bergi

Comment: Yes, that line is replacing the method by a stub, and you shouldn't be doing that. You should be *calling* the method - and not in the `before` block, but in the actual test!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I want to test for ``throw error``. How will I achieve that if I dont stub it? As at the moment when I have it as a stub if I try to invoke the method like this ``await userService.findOneUser(fakeId)`` I get errors because I stubbed it to ``throws``. If I remove the stub I cant check/make a test for ``throw error`` inside the method from userService.js @Bergi

Comment: Below I posted a way around answer is my below answer what you meant? Let me know thanks! @Bergi

Comment: You mock/stub `User.findOne` and tell it to throw. Then you call your `userService.findOneUser` method - no stubbing! - and expect it to call `findOne` and propagate the exception.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I have managed to make my test work. Have a look at my two solutions in my answer post, is my second solution what you mean in your comment? Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I think this might be the solution to my problem strange but it works the tests is working with this

```
    describe.only("findOne() throws error", async () => {
      const errors = customError(404, "User not found"); // correct throw
      const errors1 = customError(404, "User not foundss"); // on purpose to see if the test fails if should.throw(errors1) is placed instead of should.throw(errors) 

      after(() => {
        sinon.reset()
      });

      // made it work
      it("call User.findOne() with incorrect parameter, and throws an error,  works some how! ", async () => {
        userResult = sinon.spy(userService.findOneUser);
        try {
          mockModels.User.findOne.withArgs({ where: { id: fakeId } }).threw(errors);
          await userResult(fakeId);
        } catch(e) {
          // pass without having catch the test fails ‍
        } finally {
          expect(mockModels.User.findOne).to.have.been.calledWith({ where: { id: fakeId } });
        }
      });

      it("throws error user does not exist,,, WORKS", () => {
        expect(mockModels.User.findOne.withArgs(fakeId).throws(errors)).to.throw
        mockModels.User.findOne.withArgs(fakeId).should.throw(errors); // specially this part without having the catch test fails. but now test works even tested with errors1 variable
        expect(userResult).to.throw;
      });
    });
```

---

---

---

**MORE CLEANER SOLUTION BELOW**

I like this solution more as I call the method inside within the `describe` block, then I do the test of the two `it` blocks.

The problem was I should not have stubbed the class method but should have called it directly, or used `sinon.spy` on the method and call it through the spy. As for checking that the errors are as expected then running this line of `expect(mockModels.User.findOne.withArgs(fakeId).throws(errors)).to.throw(errors);` was the solution I needed.

```
    describe.only('findOne() user does not exists, most cleanest throw solution', () => {
      after(() => {
        sinon.reset()
      });
      const errors = customError(404, "User not found");

      mockModels.User.findOne.withArgs({ where: { id: fakeId } }).threw(errors);
      userResult = sinon.spy(userService, "findOneUser"); // either invoke the through sinon.spy or invoke the method directly doesnt really matter
      userResult(fakeId);
      // userResult = userService.findOneUser(fakeId); // invoke the method directly or invoke through sinon.spy from above

      it('call User.findOne() with invalid parameter is called', () => {
        expect(mockModels.User.findOne).to.have.been.calledWith({ where: { id: fakeId } });
      })
      it('test to throw the error', () => {
        expect(mockModels.User.findOne.withArgs(fakeId).throws(errors)).to.throw(errors);
        expect(userResult).to.throw;
      })
    });
```